# Cart automatically empty after 2 hour

Tags: cart, addtocart

I add the product in cart at 10:00 am then when i refresh the page at 12:00 pm i see cart is empty automatically .
I check the admin settings there are we set the time [ 31536000 ] in Persistence Lifetime (seconds)  which is almost 1 year .
In the admin Cookie Lifetime is also [ 31536000 ] .
In php.ini file [ session.gc_maxlifetime ] is also more then 2 hours .
But the cart is empty after hours .
I set 300 seconds then the cart empty after 5 min but if i set more then 31536000 or any other time which is more then 2 hours time then cart empty after 2 hours automatically .
I check the log files to look out for any error in logs but there are no errors in log files.
Could anyone suggest regarding this so i can proceed forward.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if there is a cron job or module that is affecting or maybe there is an issue with the caching mechanism in Magento, you may want to check your cache settings to make sure that they are configured correctly and the cache is not cleared prematurely.

Comment: Thanks , I already check the cache settings they are configured correctly and cache is cleared too , we have not any cron job which is related to this .